# How to refer to the second-person plural explicitly and political correctly?

Tags: word-usage

Some say "you guys" is sexist.

Some say "you people" is racist.

http://ja.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=You+People

> While the phrase has long been used as an interpersonal generalization,
>   it has become known as a racial epithet targeted to blacks only recently.

Comment: I have trouble imagining that anyone would seriously call "you people" racist. Citation?

Comment: @NathanTuggy - It's times like this I really wish I could post media in comments: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPxs0Qh72kY

Comment: Why not just "you"?

Comment: @stangdon: ... well, that's a thing. But it doesn't seem like anybody else understood or agreed with that guy.

Comment: @user3169 Just "you" can be ambiguous. It could mean "anybody", which is singular.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't add any context, so how would I know? Anyway most forms of "you (some personification)" will not be politically correct, and are looking downward at best.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - It's really just a joke, which you have to have seen the movie to get.  Anyway, no, I don't think "you people" is really a racist thing to say, but it has unfortunately been the kind of thing that racist people say, as in "Why don't **you people**..."

Comment: @NathanTuggy Please see my edit.

Comment: @user3169 "Yes, but you didn't add any context, so how would I know?"
I took it for granted that just "you" is ambiguous.
I believe it's a matter of course for native English speakers.

Answer (score 2):

You could try **"You folks"**

Trying to avoid being seen as politically incorrect is, in some circles, a difficult task. So much depends on context and the listener's expectations.

I've often heard women athletes refer to the other women on their team as "you guys": "Come on, you guys, we need to play better."

When spoken to an individual of one race by a person of another race, "you people" very often is a code word for the race of the first person, and being a code word makes it offensive. In most circles, "The black community has a relatively high crime rate" is not particularly racist, while "You people have a high crime rate" is. Of course, in some circles, ANY criticism, or perceived criticism of the black community by a white person is a priori racism, regardless of factual validity.

In the military, "you people" is often used as part of (often intense) criticism, without any implication of racism. "You people need to get your act together, and do it now!"

Answer (score 1):

I typically use **"you all"**. It avoids problems with referring to one group, and sounds more natural than "you people".

(Sometimes I also use **"you guys"**, but that's *only* when I'm with a group of friends who are more relaxed and understand that I'm using it in a gender-neutral way.)